# onPostexecute in Fragment calling method on view is safe?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Below there is asynctask which is updating in database status of pinned article/marked as favourite. After update, I invalidate actionbar icon to change it from not selected bookmark into selected.

[image]

Is it memory leak safe to call in onPostExecute any methods on declared fields like view? Is it necessary to create WeakReference of view?

I take into account the extreme situation in which fragment is not added.
Asynctask is executed in onStart() method of fragment.

```
new PinAsyncTask(articleId) {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean pinned) {
        if (isAdded()) {
            supportActionBar.invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
}.execute(mArticleInfoCv);
```

Comment: Is this bookmark a menu item ?

Comment: yes, in actionbar there is menuItem with icon as above

Comment: I think you have correctly implemented. There should be no need of weakReference or no memory leak will occur as you have checked isAdded(). (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its safe to manipulate views on both `onPreExecute`, `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` methods of `AsyncTask`. Please refer to the [official android docs for AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)